# Is there a way to use retrofit with POJO's setters?

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a REST API and i use Retrofit library for calling request.
For exmaple i have a some POJO (Dialog.java):

```
   public class Dialog {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("dialogId")
    private int _id;

    @Expose
    private String opponentLogin;


    public void setOpponentLogin(String opponentLogin) {            
        // these should be some magic with opponentLogin before it can be saved in memory
        this.opponentLogin = opponentLogin;
    }


    public String getOpponentLogin() {            
        return opponentLogin;
    }
}
```

And some call method from my ApiManager:

```
public void getDialogList() {
    Call<List<Dialog>> call = service.getDialogList();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Dialog>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Dialog>> response) {
            switch (response.code()) {
                case 200:
                    // work with POJO object
                    break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            // TODO no internet connection
        }
    });
}
```

The question is: can i call `setOpponentLogin` method (and some other setter) when retrofit convert JSON answer to POJO?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this with setter methods. Setter methods is used for uploading some contents to API like some text and images. It depends upon your API whether to use raw JSON body or something else.

Comment: If i understant you, i should use
Call<JSONObject> instead Call<List<Dialog>> and convert it manually to my POJO via getString, getLong, etc JSONObject methods?

Comment: No. Retrofit do this automatically if you created POJO. You do not need to parse manually.Refer this link for example. http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/

Comment: Hm, i can't understand why, but setOpponentLogin didn't called from retrofit enqueue method

Comment: I want to call a setter when I have got some response back from API call enqueue but couldnot be able to, you got something?

Comment: @PrakharaM Why you want to do that? Response is already in your variable.